# EC2 - should I attach old volumes to new generation instances

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm creating new generation memory optimized EC2 instances and need to attach existing EBS data volumes.

Is there such a thing a a "new generation" volume or do the new generation features live only on my root volume?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just create an AMI from the existing EC2 instance, then create a new memory optizied instance from that AMI vs. linking volumes?

Comment: When trying to create a "new generation" instance such as a memory optimized instance from an old-generation based AMI, the newgens are X'd out from yours selection options, you cannot select them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can only keep your existing volumes to attach if the new instance exists in the same zone as the volumes.  Otherwise you'll need to make a copy of the volume.

Attaching the existing volumes within the same zone should not result in better or worse performance assuming you're not changing the storage volume type, say (SSD, provisioned SSD, Magnetic).

If you're on Non-SSD, you'll definitely get a boost if move to an SSD volume.  If you're using a new memory optimized instance you'll want SSD backed storage.

Comment: Isn't SSD the default when you create a new volume?

Comment: @dancoleman For the new instances yes, non-provisioned, but you can also choose provisioned or Magnetic.